# Querying a model by a many_many relationship with Silverstripe DataModel

Tags: silverstripe

If i have a Model DebatePage which has the following many many relationship:

```
 private static $many_many = array(
    'Panelists'     => 'Panelist'
  );
```

and the panelist has a text field called "Name"

How can i query for all the debates that have a panelist called bob?

```
DebatePage::get()->filter('Panelist.Name:partialmatch', $keyword);
```

but i get an unknown column error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was nearly there

```
DebatePage::get()->filter('Panelists.Name:partialmatch', $keyword);
```

So I just needed to use the relationship name, not singularised.  Amazing how good SS data model is.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing except my many_many object is actually a Page not a DataObject so i have `EventPage::get()->filter('Areas.Title:partialmatch', $area)` (Areas is actually AreaPage). But i get a mysql error :(